# Image files dosen't print correctly in windows fax service

Tags: fax

I've written some codes to send fax using faxcomlib. it work fine when running code in my windows application but i want to use my sending fax code in a windows service,the problem is go here when i try to send fax by using windows service, my problem is that when i sending text files,or pdf or word document it work fine,but when sending any image format like .jpg,.tiff,... i face to operation failed error and my service get hanged,i try this ways but unfortunately i didn't get any right anwser :
1- i get all permissions to my service and related folders
2- i try to convert images to the same format and size that fax printer use it ( CCITT T6 - 1740*2400)
3- i try to convert my images to pdf files and then send it but i cann't, despite already i did send pdf files without any errors.
and here is my codes for sendig fax :

```
 if (ImageExtensions.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetExtension(tempFileName).ToUpperInvariant().Trim()))
                    {
                        string newFileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Temp\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(currentAttachment) + ".tif";
                        Toranj.Base.Graphic.Imaging.SaveTiff(tempFileName, newFileName);
                        Bitmap tempImage = new Bitmap(tempFileName);
                        System.Drawing.Image newImage =              Toranj.Base.Graphic.Imaging.Resize(tempImage, 1728, 2200, RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXY, 204, 196);
                        tempImage.Dispose();
                        System.IO.File.Delete(tempFileName);
                        newImage.Save(tempFileName);
                        newImage.Dispose();
                        Toranj.Base.Graphic.Imaging.SaveTiff(tempFileName, newFileName);
                        //PdfDocument doc = new PdfDocument();
                        //doc.Pages.Add(new PdfPage());
                        //XGraphics xgr = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(doc.Pages[0]);
                        //XImage img = XImage.FromFile(tempFileName);
                        //xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
                        //doc.Save(newFileName);
                        //doc.Close();
                        fileList.Add(newFileName);
                        System.IO.File.Delete(tempFileName);
                    }
                    else
                        fileList.Add(tempFileName);
                }
                FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument currentDocument = new FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument();
                string[] attachList = fileList.ToArray();
                currentDocument.Bodies = attachList;
                ShamsiDate curretnDate = new ShamsiDate(DateTime.Now);
                currentDocument.DocumentName = "fax:" + curretnDate.PerSimpleDate();
                currentDocument.Priority = FAXCOMEXLib.FAX_PRIORITY_TYPE_ENUM.fptHIGH;
                currentDocument.Recipients.Add(currentRow["faxNumber"].ToString(), currentRow["RecipientName"].ToString());
                currentDocument.AttachFaxToReceipt = true;
                currentDocument.Sender.Title = "xxxxx";
                currentDocument.Sender.Name = "";
                currentDocument.Sender.City = "xxxxx";
                currentDocument.Sender.Company = "xxxxx";
                currentDocument.Sender.Country = "xxxxx";
                currentDocument.Sender.Email = "xxxxx";
                currentDocument.Sender.FaxNumber = "";
                currentDocument.Sender.HomePhone = "";
                currentDocument.Sender.TSID = "";
                currentDocument.Sender.SaveDefaultSender();
                object jobsId = new object();
                currentDocument.ConnectedSubmit2(sendServer, out jobsId);
                string[] jobID = (string[])jobsId;
```

can anyone help me?
in above code, if my files was image format files, i'll first change size,and save them az tiff format and convert it to the pdf format file to sending by fax but there is no change!!!

Comment: did you find the answer to this?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: unfortunatly No,i has to change my solution and use windows application to send fax instead of windows server, if you use windows application never face with such error.

Comment: Which windows application do you use?

Comment: I use a simple windows application base on C# programing an run that on the taskbar,in this case when the program send or receive any fax,it will inform user to current application.

Comment: not sure this will work for us because our customers send out many faxes, but will consider it if no other solution will be found. Thank you.

Comment: we has the same problem,but, unfortunately we didn't find any other solution,in other hand i think that our customers are more happy to see their faxes status.